# date format in java for DD and dd

Tags: java

What is the wrong with this format , commented format is throwing exception ,
Please help me with this dd and DD in java for date format.

```
    SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddmm");
//  SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyDDMM");
     dformat.setLenient(false);
     dformat.parse("20121010");
```

**Exception :**
Error: Unparseable date: "20121010"

Comment: `D` is the `day in year` not the `day in month`. Besides `mm` is for the minutes, not the months (use `MM`) See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: What exception it is throwing?

Comment: I think you want yyyyddMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`D` (Capital) is used to indicate `DAY IN YEAR` like `123`,`300`,etc.

While `d` (small-lowercase) is used to indicate `DAY OF MONTH` like `12`,`25`, Here values like `36` will not be valid.

[Javadoc explains all the letters that you can use in SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 4):

its case sensitive.

D stands for day in a year, d stands for day in a month.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

`DD` means "day in year" so you are trying to parse a date that has 10-th month (October) and 10-th day of year (which is definitely in January) at the same time which is impossible.  `"20121001"` will be parsed fine (1-th month (January) and 10-th day of the year).